# How to set webview editable false in JavaFX

Tags: java, webview, javafx, javafx-2

I have a webview that loads HTMLEditor's text. I don't want it to be editable. can anyone help?

thanks.

Comment: A WebView is [not editable](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#contenteditable) by default.  What is the issue?

Comment: It was for using HTML Editor. the issue solved by changing contenteditable to false.

Answer (score 4):

```
HTMLEditor htmlEd=new HTMLEditor();
String st=htmlEd.getHtmlText();
WebView browser=new WebView();                     
WebEngine webEngine=browser.getEngine();

if(st.contains("contenteditable=\"true\"")){
    st=st.replace("contenteditable=\"true\"", "contenteditable=\"false\"");
}
webEngine.loadContent(st);
```

I solved my problem in this way.